# FineUploader Pause if PDF

Tags: fine-uploader

I would like to pause fineuploader if the document dropped is a pdf to give the end user some options before continuing. I cannot figure out how to get the pause to trigger. I am getting [Fine Uploader 5.3.2] Ignoring pause for file ID 0 (DEVELOPMENT.PDF).  Not in progress.

My code below.

```
var uploader = new qq.s3.FineUploader({
        debug: true,
        element: document.getElementById('fine-uploader'),    
        request: {
            endpoint: 'bucketname.s3.amazonaws.com',        
            accessKey: 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ' //zone-user key id        
        },
        signature: {                    
            endpoint: "/assets/plugins/fine-uploader/signature/endpoint.php"
        },
        debug:true,
        cors: {expected: true},
        chunking: {enabled: true},
        resume: {enabled: true},    
        deleteFile:{enabled:false},
        validation: {
            itemLimit: 5,
            sizeLimit: 15000000
        },
        uploadSuccess:{
            //endpoint:"/assets/plugins/fine-uploader/signature/endpoint.php?success"
        },
        callbacks: {          
            onSubmitted: function(id, name) {            
                var fileName = name;
                var fileExtension = fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf('.') + 1).toUpperCase();
                    if(fileExtension==='PDF'){
                        alert('it IS pdf... now what?');
                        jQuery('#confirmPDFHandler').modal();
                        uploader.pauseUpload(id); //not pausing here                          
                    }else{
                        alert('its not a pdf... go!');
                        uploader.continueUpload(id);
                    }
            },
            onError: function(id, name, errorReason, xhrOrXdr) {
                //alert(qq.format("Error on file number {} - {}.  Reason: {}", id, name, errorReason));
            },
            onUpload: function(id, name, isError,responseJSON) {
                var obj = JSON.stringify(responseJSON);
                //alert(name + 'is in progress');
            },
            onComplete: function(id,fileId,responseJSON){
                var newfilename=uploader.getKey(id);                    
            }
        },   
        retry: {enableAuto: false}
    });
```

Comment: You can't pause an upload that has not yet started. What exactly are you asking of your user? How will you use the input from your user to affect the upload(s)?

Comment: We are developing a pdf splitter. If the user drops a pdf in the uploader, we will give them an option to simply upload (continue as usual) or split the file (pause or stop the upload and run our separate custom code to begin the pdf split option pulling one document into multiple documents then passing those to an uploader). Hope that makes sense. I thought about disallowing PDFs and handling them separately, but I would like them to opt to continue if there is no split necessary.

Answer (score 0):

> If the user drops a pdf in the uploader, we will give them an option to simply upload (continue as usual) or split the file (pause or stop the upload and run our separate custom code to begin the pdf split option pulling one document into multiple documents then passing those to an uploader)

Sounds like you want to potentially cancel the upload, or proceed. In that case, you should ask the user for input inside of an `onSubmit` or `onValidate` event handler. [Your handler should return a `Promise` and either resolve the promise to allow the file to go through, or reject it to cancel the file submission](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/features/async-tasks-and-promises.html). For example:

```
onSubmit: function(id) {
   return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      // popup modal
      // when user responds...
      // ...call resolve() if they want to upload the file
      // ...or reject() if they want to cancel the file
   });
}
```

Fine Uploader has a very small "promise" implementation bundled with the library. It's non-standard, so you may be better off finding a standard A+ implementation instead.